# Как из одного класса вызвать другой класс?

Tags: java

Как сделать, чтобы из одного класса перейти к другому классу?
Например, имеются определённые условия, при которых должен начать выполнение один класс, а при других условиях другой.

Comment: Создать экземпляр нужного класса через `new` и вызвать нужный метод.

Answer (score 1):

Класс не может выполняться. Выполняется код, который находится в классе. Чтобы это происходило, необходимо создать экземпляр класса, т.е. объект класса.

Обычно объекты взаимодействуют посредством передачи параметров. То есть когда вы передаете один объект другому с помощью метода. Хотя это может быть и конструктор, или интерсептор, или ДИ, АОП.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод рефакторинга "Замена условного оператора полиморфизмом", чтобы решить этот вопрос корректно.

Почему бы не создать один абстрактный класс, сделав несколько наследником и переопределив его базовые методы по своему, а затем при определенных условиях создать объект необходимого класса и вызвать его метод.
Более подробно: https://refactoring.guru/ru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Пример:

```
abstract class Bird {
  //...
  abstract double getSpeed();
}

class European extends Bird {
  double getSpeed() {
    return getBaseSpeed();
  }
}
class African extends Bird {
  double getSpeed() {
    return getBaseSpeed() - getLoadFactor() * numberOfCoconuts;
  }
}
class NorwegianBlue extends Bird {
  double getSpeed() {
    return (isNailed) ? 0 : getBaseSpeed(voltage);
  }
}

// Somewhere in client code
speed = bird.getSpeed();
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы наследовать класс, достаточно вставить имя наследуемого класса с использованием ключевого слова extends:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

}
В этом коде мы наследуемся от класса Activity и добавляем свой код, который будет отвечать за наше приложение.